# make collapse sidebar like AdminLTE with jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want make a collapsed side bar like this one [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html#).

But I've got a problem. How do I do it with CSS and jQuery?

I tried this one but it's not working.

Here is my [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWERVa).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
  .sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 225px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3A3A3A;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation.active {
  background-color: red;
  /*background-image: url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-VbfWt8Zlo8s/V7GrsnNyI3I/AAAAAAAAD_0/vzR5BsD0fgoQ7nHtcNjaDt9F0kyYhUeLACLcB/s1600/3lines.png);
 background-size: 55px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
}

.navigation {
  width: 225px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #555555;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.list {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 225px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.list.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 75px;
}

.line {
  padding: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  /*font-size: 30px;
 font-family: Arial;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.line.show {
  padding: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  /*font-size: 30px;
 font-family: Arial;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <doctype></doctype>
  <title>Administrator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <button class="navigation" title="Click Here!"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></button>
    <div class="list">
      <ul>
        <li class="line"><i class="material-icons">menu</i>Line 1</li>
        <li class="line"><i class="material-icons">menu</i>Line 2</li>
        <li class="line"><i class="material-icons">menu</i>Line 3</li>
        <li class="line"><i class="material-icons">menu</i>Line 4</li>
        <li class="line"><i class="material-icons">menu</i>Line 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Link is not working.  Please include the key bits of your code in the question.

Comment: added snippet, fixed codepen link